# (iOS) alpha not works when run app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have hours trying to solve this and researching about this problem without results. This is my problem:

I'm using a ViewController in a existing project and over this I use an UIIMageView and a UIView at the same level. Then I set them alpha value in these two elements (alpha = 0.5) using Interface Builder. When I run the project on Simulator the alpha value not make effect and they looks like with their alpha value = 1. I made this same procedure in a new project and when I run the alpha effect is visible. I tried check/uncheck opaque option, set alpha value programatically as property or using method setAlpha, as well as set opaque value with code and it doesn't works. This problem happens with device too.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: please check if you're changing the alpha again to 1

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore It works in this way:
First a UIView is set alpha 0 but I can see the View as alpha 1. When I move another view modifying location.y, it refresh and alpha in that View is visible and works normally

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you import

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

UIIMageView.alpha = 0.4;
```

**OR** check with this

```
UIImage *wheelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wheel@2x.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:wheelImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, wheelImage.size.width,  wheelImage.size.height);
imageView.alpha = 0.2;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Yes, it has UIKit and I have the same result

Comment: is UIIMageView imageView?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
-----
[_image setAlpha:0.5];
----
_image.alpha = 0.5
--- 
This with code

Comment: sorry but with your code I had the same result: an image without alpha

Comment: 3 comments before me is code and if I write this code in a new project I can see the alpha, but in the current project not

Comment: one comment to your code @JavierLanda-Torres:  IBOutlet's should be declared as `weak`, not `strong`: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;`

Comment: if the above code does not affect alpha then connecting with IBOutlet will never solve this issue. You have problem elsewhere, which should be detected first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to connect your outlet in the storyboard and the property?

Comment: knutigro: no! it is connect!